# When the last Bitcoin block is mined, how would transactions continue?

Tags: mining-theory, reward-schedule

If transactions are stored in Bitcoin blocks through Merkle trees, when the last Bitcoin block is mined, how would there be future Bitcoin transactions? Where would those transactions be stored on?

Answer (score 1):

A misunderstanding. I do not know what leads you to believe that there will be a last block.

It is true that block rewards have a halving period and will eventually, in many years, reach zero, but, the transaction fees are also paid to the miner so mining will continue.

Comment: I think i've been mixing up bitcoin with blocks, that's where the misunderstanding comes from, thanks! But so there's a finite number of bitcoins, but an infinite number of blocks?

Comment: @S.L. Yes, that is correct.